# How comes properties act like functions?

Tags: javascript, properties, getter

If you install [colors](https://github.com/marak/colors.js/) you will see you can write scripts like this:

```
var colors = require('colors');

console.log('hello'.green);
console.log('i like cake and pies'.underline.red)
console.log('inverse the color'.inverse);
console.log('OMG Rainbows!'.rainbow);
console.log('Run the trap'.trap);
```

How is is possible that properties behave like functions (like `[5, 6, 4].count`?).

I understand `'Run the trap'.trap()` but not `'Run the trap'.trap`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript allows you to define getters for setters and properties (even on prototypes):

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'count', {
    get: function () {
        return this.length;
    }
});

console.log([1, 2, 3].count);
```

Use sparingly. colors, specifically, [uses the non-standard `__defineGetter__` function instead](https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/blob/13dd5a84e32a584f06579df5e09878778a79d32e/lib/extendStringPrototype.js#L9), but to the same effect.

Comment: Is this an all-time JavaScript behavior or very recent one?

Comment: @OlivierPons: `Object.defineProperty` is ES5, and `__defineGetter__` has existed in many engines for longer. It hasn’t been around since the beginning of JavaScript, no.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "testing", {
    get: function() {
        return this.string + ' some test message ';
    }
});
console.log( 'my string'.testing ); // my string some test message
```

Comment: Is this an all-time JavaScript behavior or very recent one?

Comment: @OlivierPons it was implemented in ECMAScript 5.1